# Putting box plot below scatter plot [Plotly]

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want a box plot to be placed on top of a scatter plot.
Neither putting the box trace at first and adding the scatter plot on top nor adding an "layer='below'" attribute leads to the desired result. The box always stays in the back.
Any suggestions?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(10)
rand = np.random.uniform(-100, 100, 100)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    x=rand,
    name='Markers',
    line_color='rgba(128, 128, 128, .0)',
    fillcolor='darkgrey'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=rand,
    y=['Markers']*len(rand),
    name='Markers',
    mode="markers",
    marker_color='orange',
    marker_size=8,
    # layer='below' # does not work
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/boxplot-trace-behind-area-traces/33663), you have to attach the box plot to another axis:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    x=rand,
    name='Markers',
    line_color='rgba(128, 128, 128, .0)',
    fillcolor='darkgrey',
    yaxis='y2'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=rand,
    y=['Markers']*len(rand),
    name='Markers',
    mode="markers",
    marker_color='orange',
    marker_size=8
#     layer='below' # does not work
))
fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(
        matches='y',
        layer="above traces",
        overlaying="y",       
    ),)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot :)